# Should the MAX-ACCESS field of the index (key) of a MIB table always be not-accessible?

Tags: snmp, mib

Is it a hard and fast rule to set the index of a MIB table to be not-accessible?

Answer (score 7):

A MAX-ACCESS can take any of the four values: `read-only`, `read-write`, `write-only`, `not-accessible`. From this source:http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPMIBObjectsObjectCharacteristicsandObjectTypes-2.htm

Table 205: SNMP SMI Version 2 Max-Access Values

```
Max-Access Value       Description

read-create            Object can be read, written or created.

read-write             Object can be read or written.

read-only              Object can only be read.

accessible-for-notify  Object can be used only using SNMP notification (SNMP traps).

not-accessible         Used for special purposes.
```

Here is an example where values other than `not-accessible` are used: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4625.txt :

```
t11FcRouteStorageType OBJECT-TYPE
SYNTAX      StorageType
MAX-ACCESS  read-create
STATUS      current
DESCRIPTION
       "The storage type for this conceptual row.
       Conceptual rows having the value 'permanent' need not
       allow write-access to any columnar objects in the row."
   DEFVAL { nonVolatile }
::= { t11FcRouteEntry 12 }
```

More information can be found here: http://www.simple-times.org/pub/simple-times/issues/1-4.html

> The ACCESS clause has been renamed to MAX-ACCESS in order to clarify that it specifies the maximum access which makes ''protocol sense'', and the values are ordered, from least to greatest, as follows: ''not-accessible'', ''read-only'', ''read-write'', ''read-create''. The ''read-create'' value is used for write-able objects in a conceptual row for which new instances can be created via network management. Another change is the recommended use of ''not-accessible'' for auxiliary objects (those objects defined in a table solely for use in identifying a conceptual row).

Comment: thanks 4 d answer.. 1 thing t11FcRouteStorageType is not an Index in the table t11FcRouteTable.. actually I was looking for an Index whose MAX-ACCESS was not not-accessible ie I want to know why most of the the times indices of a table are not-accessible?

Answer (score 5):

MAX-ACCESS for INDEX objects should always be `not-accessible` in SMIv2 modules, except in certain circumstances. Per [RFC 2578](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2578.txt) (Structure of Management Information Version 2) section 7.7(6):

> Objects which are both specified in the INDEX clause of a
>   conceptual    row and also columnar objects of the same conceptual row
>   are termed    auxiliary objects.  The MAX-ACCESS clause for auxiliary
>   objects is    "not-accessible", except in the following circumstances:
>
> (1)  within a MIB module originally written to conform to SMIv1, and
>        later converted to conform to SMIv2; or
>
> (2)  a conceptual row must contain at least one columnar object which
>   is
>        not an auxiliary object.  In the event that all of a conceptual
>        row's columnar objects are also specified in its INDEX clause, then
>        one of them must be accessible, i.e., have a MAX-ACCESS clause of
>        "read-only". (Note that this situation does not arise for a
>        conceptual row allowing create access, since such a row will have a
>        status column which will not be an auxiliary object.)